# How to implement a grid using arrays with a given size?

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to create a simple board in a draw_board definition that will use size and several coordinates where I will place 1 character length characters in specified coordinates. I am in the beginning stages and want to just simply create the board itself using a 2d array.

This method below works when I change individual elements :

```
board = [['','','',''], ['','','',''], ['', '', '', ''], ['','','','']]
board[0][0] = 'a'

print('   0  1  2  3')
print('0  ' + board[0][0] + '  ' + board[0][1] + '  ' + board[0][2] + '  ' + board[0][3])
print('1  ' + board[1][0] + '  ' + board[1][1] + '  ' + board[1][2] + '  ' + board[1][3])
print('2  ' + board[2][0] + '  ' + board[2][1] + '  ' + board[2][2] + '  ' + board[2][3])
print('3  ' + board[3][0] + '  ' + board[3][1] + '  ' + board[3][2] + '  ' + board[3][3])
```

However, I would not be able to change the size by just a variable and would need to edit the initialization of the board myself.

This method below is better and *would* work because I could easily change the size variable and get any size board I want...

```
size = 4
board = [['']*size]*size
board[0][0] = 'a'

print('   0  1  2  3')
print('0  ' + board[0][0] + '  ' + board[0][1] + '  ' + board[0][2] + '  ' + board[0][3])
print('1  ' + board[1][0] + '  ' + board[1][1] + '  ' + board[1][2] + '  ' + board[1][3])
print('2  ' + board[2][0] + '  ' + board[2][1] + '  ' + board[2][2] + '  ' + board[2][3])
print('3  ' + board[3][0] + '  ' + board[3][1] + '  ' + board[3][2] + '  ' + board[3][3])
```

**However**, when I implement board[0][0] = 'a', it changes the entire column to 'a', which is not what I want. Any suggestions of how I could change this second method to make it work for just the desired coordinate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

`board = [['' for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)]`

this is because when you use the `*` operator, you're creating more references to the same object, not more copies.

Here's more in depth information about the strategy used above, called [**list comprehensions**](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)